# How to run DiffMerge with arguments within applescript?

Tags: applescript, automator

Ideally I have these inputs:

```
set appId to "com.sourcegear.DiffMerge"
set path1 to "/tmp/file1.txt"
set path2 to "/tmp/file2.txt"
```

and need to run the app using appId with given arguments.

I know how to run the app using appId but that doesn't pass the args.

```
tell application id appId to activate
```

or I can run the app and pass the args but I don't know how to get the path from appId

```
set diff_path to "/Applications/pp/dev/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge"
set cmd to diff_path & " '" & path1 & "' '" & path2 & "'"
do shell script cmd
```

Do you know how to either ran `activate` with args or how to get full path from appId?

Answer (score 0):

Not completely certain of your full intentions here but assuming that you wish to utilize diffmerge's command line capabilities in an applescript, try something like this:

```
set appID to "com.sourcegear.DiffMerge"
set appIDO to application id "com.sourcegear.DiffMerge"
set diff_path to quoted form of POSIX path of (path to appIDO) & "Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge"
set path1 to quoted form of "/tmp/file1.txt"
set path2 to quoted form of "/tmp/file2.txt"
set cmd to diff_path & space & path1 & space & path2
do shell script cmd
```

It will run this shell command:

`"'/Applications/pp/dev/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge' '/tmp/file1.txt' '/tmp/file2.txt'"`

The `quoted form` code wraps the text in single quotes so that there is no further interpretation of it by the shell. It's probably not an issue for your specific example but in case any of the paths or filenames gets a space, it shouldn't cause an error. The `space` does the obvious. If you wanted, you could compress the above into fewer lines.

For more information on how applescript handles 'do shell', look up an apple technical note TN2065 (it's easy to find). I should add that the activate command isn't part of this process. That command would make diffmerge the active application (and depending… might cause a window to open).

### Update:

`path to appID` triggers the launching of the app and I'm not aware of any method of suppressing that.

It is possible to piece together the path to an app's CLI tool but it is not as general — specifically around nested folders in /Applications.

```
set sName to "DiffMerge"
set cName to "DiffMerge"

set aPath to path to (applications folder) as text
set sFol to ":Contents:MacOS:"
--> ":Contents:MacOS:"

set gApp to aPath & sName & ".app"
--> "MacHD:Applications:DiffMerge.app"

set cTool to aPath & gApp & sFol & cName
--> "MacHD:Applications:DiffMerge.app:Contents:MacOS:DiffMerge"

set cmdPath to quoted form of POSIX path of cTool
--> "'/Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge'"


set path1 to quoted form of "/tmp/file1.txt"
set path2 to quoted form of "/tmp/file2.txt"

cmdPath & space & path1 & space & path2
--> "'/Applications/MacHD/Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge' '/tmp/file1.txt' '/tmp/file2.txt'"
```

Comment: This is what I want. It's ALMOST there. In your code the diff_path points to DiffMerge.app directory which "do shell script" doesn't run. In my tests it must point to the actual binary which is "DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge". Otherwise I got: error "sh: /Applications/pp/dev/DiffMerge.app/: is a directory"

Comment: Hard to test without the app but that makes sense. So basically you have to concatenate the diff_path and the DiffMerge executable's path after that point: `POSIX path of (path to appIDO) & "Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge"`

Comment: Is there any way to make it generic for the appId? So if works with other appIds as well. Perhaps just a simple "hack" to read the last path component "DiffMerge" from the (path to appIDO).lastPathComponent.withoutExtension?

Comment: One interesting note about unwanted behavior: this code "set appId to application id ..." actually runs the application. Is there any alternative without running the app?

Comment: In line 3, everything up to 'DiffMerge' is generic (well except that you have the app in a sub-dir of /Applications but since you're asking for the app that's not an issue). You could modify the line's ending with something like `& "Contents/MacOS/" & appName`. Also, you can use `set appID to app "Whatever"` and then `get (path to appID)`.